# The list of all .com and .net whois servers?

Tags: dns, whois, verisign

I'm trying to find the list of all whois servers for COM/NET.
Verisign is the authoritative registry for the .com, .net, .name, .cc and .tv domains.

**Possible solution:**
To find out the complete list of whois servers is to crawl through at least a million of them (via whois.crsnic.net) using the domain list from the .com zone file and read the official whois from the whois result.

That way I could probably build a 90%+ complete list. I'm ready to go that route and post a result here but if anybody knows a better way/source, please do help. Thank you!

Comment: What is the need exactly? What do you gain by such list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found all the accredited registrars on Verisign website, crawled their whois with each company name and got the whois server.

Here's a list of all the whois servers for .com and .net in PHP array:

```
$servers = array(
    "whois.godaddy.com",
    "whois.networksolutions.com",
    "whois.enom.com",
    "whois.name.com",
    "whois.tucows.com",
    "whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com",
    "whois.register.com",
    "whois.wildwestdomains.com",
    "whois.markmonitor.com",            
    "whois2.softlayer.com",
    "whois2.domain.com",
    "whois.zoomregistrar.com",
    "whois.zonecasting.com",
    "whois.zigzagnames.com",
    "whois.yovole.com",        
    "whois.yournamemonkey.com",
    "whois.yourjungle.com",
    "whois.yourjungle.com",
    "whois.yourdomainnameregistrar.com",        
    "whois.yourdomainking.com",
    "whois.your-server.de",
    "whois.youdamain.com",
    "whois.yesnic.com",        
    "whois.yellowstart.com",
    "whois.worthydomains.com",
    "whois.worldbizdomains.com",
    "whois.world4you.com",
    "whois.willamettenames.com",
    "whois.whatisyourdomain.com",
    "whois.west263.com",
    "whois.welcomedomain.com",
    "whois.webzero.com",
    "whois.websitesource.com",
    "whois.website.ws",        
    "whois.webnic.cc",        
    "whois.webnames.ru",
    "whois.webnames.ca",
    "whois.webmasters.com",
    "whois.webhosting24.com",
    "whois.webbusiness.biz",
    "whois.webair.com",        
    "whois.web4africa.net",
    "whois.volusion.com",
    "whois.vividdomains.com",
    "whois.visualnames.com",
    "whois.virtualregistrar.com",
    "whois.vigson.com",        
    "whois.viennaweb.at",
    "whois.viaduc.fr",        
    "whois.vertexnames.com",
    "whois.vedacore.com",
    "whois.unpower.com",
    "whois.unifiedservers.com",
    "whois.ultraregistrar.com",
    "whois.ukrnames.com",
    "whois.udomainname.com",
    "whois.udomainname.com",
    "whois.udamain.com",
    "whois.udag.net",        
    "whois.twt.it",                
    "whois.turbosite.com.br",
    "whois.ttpia.com",        
    "whois.tropicregistry.com",
    "whois.traveldomainsincorporated.com",        
    "whois.transip.net",
    "whois.trafficnames.net",
    "whois.trafficmedia.com",
    "whois.tradestarter.com",
    "whois.tradenamed.com",
    "whois.tradeindia.com",
    "whois.tppinternet.com",
    "whois.totalregistrations.com",
    "whois.totallydomain.com",
    "whois.topsystem.com",
    "whois.toglodo.com",
    "whois.todaynic.com",
    "whois.titanichosting.com",
    "whois.tigertech.net",
    "whois.threadwise.com",
    "whois.threadwatch.com",
    "whois.threadwalker.com",
    "whois.threadagent.com",
    "whois.thirdfloordns.com",
    "whois.theregistrarservice.com",                
    "whois.thenameco.com",
    "whois.techtyrants.com",
    "whois.tagidomains.com",
    "whois.syra.com.au",
    "whois.svenskadomaner.se",
    "whois.supernameworld.com",
    "whois.subreg.cz",        
    "whois.star-domain.jp",
    "whois.sssasss.com",
    "whois.ssandomain.com",
    "whois.soyouwantadomain.com",
    "whois.softlayer.com",
    "whois.snoqulamiedomains.com",
    "whois.snappyregistrar.com",
    "whois.skykomishdomains.com",
    "whois.sitefrenzy.com",
    "whois.sipence.com",
    "whois.silverbackdomains.com",
    "whois.signdomains.com",
    "whois.sicherregister.com",
    "whois.sibername.com",
    "whois.sfn.cn",                
    "whois.seymourdomains.com",
    "whois.serverplan.com",
    "whois.secura-gmbh.de",
    "whois.searchnresq.com",
    "whois.searchname.ca",
    "whois.sdsns.com",        
    "whois.sbsnames.com",
    "whois.savethename.com",
    "whois.savemorenames.com",
    "whois.santiamdomains.com",
    "whois.sammamishdomains.com",
    "whois.safenames.net",
    "whois.rrpproxy.net",
    "whois.rockenstein.de",
    "whois.riktad.se",        
    "whois.ride-domain.com",
    "whois.rethemhosting.net",
    "whois.resellserv.com",
    "whois.resellerid.com",
    "whois.resellercamp.com",
    "whois.registrygate.com",
    "whois.registrationtek.com",
    "whois.registrar.telekom.de",
    "whois.registrar.eu",
    "whois.registrar-info.eu",
    "whois.registermatrix.com",
    "whois.register4less.com",
    "whois.register.it",
    "whois.register.eu",
    "whois.register.ca",
    "whois.reg2c.com",        
    "whois.reg.ru",                
    "whois.reclaimdomains.com",
    "whois.rebel.com",        
    "whois.rankusa.com",
    "whois.rainydaydomains.com",
    "whois.r01.ru",                
    "whois.puritynames.com",
    "whois.purenic.com",
    "whois.puredomain.com",
    "whois.psi-usa.info",
    "whois.protondomains.com",
    "whois.pronamed.com",
    "whois.profilebuilder.com",
    "whois.prodomaines.com",
    "whois.privatedomains.biz",        
    "whois.premiumregistrations.com",        
    "whois.powernamers.com",        
    "whois.powercarrier.com",        
    "whois.powerbrandsolutions.com",        
    "whois.postaldomains.com",        
    "whois.platinumregistrar.com",        
    "whois.planetdomain.com",        
    "whois.pheenix.com",        
    "whois.pearlnamingservice.com",        
    "whois.pdxprivatenames.com",        
    "whois.paycenter.com.cn",        
    "whois.pavietnam.vn",        
    "whois.pananames.com",        
    "whois.paknic.com",        
    "whois.pairnic.com",        
    "whois.pacnames.com",        
    "whois.ownregistrar.com",        
    "whois.ownidentity.com",        
    "whois.ourdomains.com",        
    "whois.oregonurls.com",        
    "whois.oregoneu.com",        
    "whois.oray.com",        
    "whois.openname.com",        
    "whois.onlinenic.com",        
    "whois.omnis.com",        
    "whois.oldworldaliases.com",        
    "whois.oldtowndomains.com",        
    "whois.octopusdomains.net",        
    "whois.notsofamousnames.com",        
    "whois.noticeddomains.com",        
    "whois.nordreg.com",        
    "whois.nominfinitum.com",        
    "whois.nominate.net",        
    "whois.nominalia.com",        
    "whois.nomer.com",        
    "whois.no-ip.com",        
    "whois.nictrade.se",        
    "whois.nicreg.com",        
    "whois.nic.ru",        
    "whois.newgreatdomains.com",        
    "whois.neudomain.com",        
    "whois.networksavior.com",        
    "whois.networking4all.com",        
    "whois.nettica.com",        
    "whois.netsavers.com",        
    "whois.netregistry.net",        
    "whois.netlogistics.com.au",        
    "whois.netjuggler.com",        
    "whois.netim.com",        
    "whois.netestate.com",        
    "whois.netdorm.com",        
    "whois.netbulk.com",        
    "whois.netart-registrar.com",        
    "whois.net4domains.com",        
    "whois.net-chinese.com.tw",        
    "whois.nerdnames.com",        
    "whois.neonic.com",        
    "whois.neen.it",        
    "whois.needservers.com",        
    "whois.nayana.com",        
    "whois.nawang.cn",        
    "whois.namware.com",        
    "whois.namevolcano.com",        
    "whois.namevault.com",        
    "whois.nameturn.com",        
    "whois.nametofame.com",        
    "whois.namethread.com",        
    "whois.nametell.com",        
    "whois.namesystem.com",        
    "whois.namestream.com",        
    "whois.namestrategies.com",        
    "whois.namesinmotion.com",        
    "whois.namesilo.com",        
    "whois.nameshere.com",        
    "whois.namesector.com",        
    "whois.namescout.com",        
    "whois.namescout.com",        
    "whois.namesbeyond.com",        
    "whois.namesay.com",        
    "whois.namesalacarte.com",        
    "whois.names4ever.com",        
    "whois.namerich.cn",        
    "whois.nameperfections.com",        
    "whois.namepanther.com",        
    "whois.namenelly.com",        
    "whois.namemax.cn",        
    "whois.nameling.com",        
    "whois.nameking.com",        
    "whois.namejolt.com",        
    "whois.namefull.com",        
    "whois.nameforward.com",        
    "whois.namefinger.com",        
    "whois.nameescape.com",        
    "whois.nameemperor.com",        
    "whois.namecroc.com",        
    "whois.namechild.com",        
    "whois.namecheap.com",        
    "whois.namebright.com",        
    "whois.namebrew.com",        
    "whois.namebake.com",        
    "whois.namearsenal.com",        
    "whois.mypreciousdomain.com",        
    "whois.myorderbox.com",        
    "whois.myorderbox.com",        
    "whois.myobnet.com",        
    "whois.mvpdomainnames.com",        
    "whois.moniker.com",        
    "whois.mobilenameservices.com",        
    "whois.misternic.com",        
    "whois.misk.com",        
    "whois.mijninternetoplossing.nl",        
    "whois.microbreweddomains.com",        
    "whois.meshdigital.com",        
    "whois.matbao.net",        
    "whois.masterofmydomains.net",        
    "whois.markbark.com",        
    "whois.maprilis.com.vn",        
    "whois.mailclub.net",        
    "whois.magicfriday.com",        
    "whois.lws.fr",        
    "whois.locaweb.com.br",        
    "whois.litedomains.com",        
    "whois.liquidnetlimited.com",        
    "whois.lexsynergy.com",        
    "whois.lemonregistry.com",        
    "whois.ledl.net",        
    "whois.lcn.com",        
    "whois.lakeodomains.com",        
    "whois.ladasdomains.com",        
    "whois.kuwaitnet.net",        
    "whois.kudo.com",        
    "whois.ksdom.kr",        
    "whois.komplex.net",        
    "whois.klaatudomains.com",        
    "whois.king-domains.com",        
    "whois.keyregistrar.com",        
    "whois.k8.com.br",        
    "whois.jungbo.net",        
    "whois.jprs.jp",        
    "whois.joker.com",        
    "whois.joinup.jp",        
    "whois.jetpackdomains.com",        
    "whois.itpan.com",        
    "whois.isregistrar.com",        
    "whois.isimtescil.net",        
    "whois.iserveyourdomain.com",        
    "whois.iregistry.com",        
    "whois.ireg.net",        
    "whois.ipxcess.com",        
    "whois.ipmirror.com",        
    "whois.intrustdomains.com",        
    "whois.internetworks.com",        
    "whois.internetters.co.uk",        
    "whois.internetdomainnameregistrar.org",        
    "whois.internet.bs",        
    "whois.interlakenames.com",        
    "whois.interdominios.com",        
    "whois.interdomain.net",        
    "whois.instinctsolutions.com",        
    "whois.instantnames.com",        
    "whois.insanenames.com",        
    "whois.initialesonline.net",        
    "whois.ininaf.com",        
    "whois.inic.ch",        
    "whois.indiatimes.com",        
    "whois.inames.co.kr",        
    "whois.imminentdomains.net",        
    "whois.imena.ua",        
    "whois.ilait.com",        
    "whois.iisp.com",        
    "whois.ihs.com.tr",        
    "whois.idindi.com",        
    "whois.idgenesis.com",        
    "whois.ibi.net",        
    "whois.iaregistry.com",        
    "whois.hyperstreet.com",        
    "whois.hupo.com",        
    "whois.http.net",        
    "whois.hotdomaintrade.com",        
    "whois.hostway.com",        
    "whois.hostingservicesinc.net",        
    "whois.hostinger.com",        
    "whois.hosting.kr",        
    "whois.hoapdi-inc.com",        
    "whois.hichina.com",        
    "whois.hectamedia.com",        
    "whois.heavydomains.net",        
    "whois.hawthornedomains.com",        
    "whois.haveaname.com",        
    "whois.gzidc.com",        
    "whois.guoxuwang.cn",        
    "whois.gungagalunga.biz",        
    "whois.groundinternet.com",        
    "whois.gradeadomainnames.com",        
    "whois.gozerdomains.com",        
    "whois.goserveyourdomain.com",        
    "whois.google.com",        
    "whois.gooddomainregistry.com",        
    "whois.gonbei.jp",        
    "whois.gomontenegrodomains.com",        
    "whois.gofullhouse.com",        
    "whois.gofrancedomains.com",        
    "whois.godomaingo.com",        
    "whois.gochinadomains.com",        
    "whois.gocanadadomains.com",        
    "whois.goaustraliadomains.com",        
    "whois.glis.in",        
    "whois.glamdomains.com",        
    "whois.gkg.net",        
    "whois.ghana.com",        
    "whois.getyername.com",        
    "whois.genious.net",        
    "whois.gatekeeperdomains.net",        
    "whois.gandi.net",        
    "whois.gamefornames.com",        
    "whois.gabia.com",        
    "whois.fushitarazu.com",        
    "whois.frontstreetdomains.com",        
    "whois.freshbreweddomains.com",        
    "whois.freeparking.co.uk",        
    "whois.flancrestdomains.com",        
    "whois.findyouaname.com",        
    "whois.findyouadomain.com",        
    "whois.finduaname.com",        
    "whois.findgooddomains.com",        
    "whois.fiducia.lv",        
    "whois.fenominal.com",        
    "whois.fabulous.com",        
    "whois.extrathreads.com",        
    "whois.extranetdeclientes.com",        
    "whois.extendnames.com",        
    "whois.experinom.com",        
    "whois.exai.com",        
    "whois.evonames.com",        
    "whois.everreadynames.com",        
    "whois.euturbo.com",        
    "whois.eurotrashnames.com",        
    "whois.europeanconnectiononline.com",        
    "whois.eurodns.com",        
    "whois.eunameflood.com",        
    "whois.epik.com",        
    "whois.entorno.es",        
    "whois.entertainmentnames.com",        
    "whois.enterprice.net",        
    "whois.enomx.com",        
    "whois.enomworld.com",        
    "whois.enomv.com",        
    "whois.enomtoo.com",        
    "whois.enomten.com",        
    "whois.enomnz.com",        
    "whois.enomgmpservices.com",        
    "whois.enomfor.com",        
    "whois.enomeu.com",        
    "whois.enomcorporate.com",        
    "whois.enombre.com",        
    "whois.enomate.com",        
    "whois.enoma1.com",        
    "whois.enom5.com",        
    "whois.enom469.com",        
    "whois.enom467.com",        
    "whois.enom463.com",        
    "whois.enom459.com",        
    "whois.enom457.com",        
    "whois.enom455.com",        
    "whois.enom453.com",        
    "whois.enom451.com",        
    "whois.enom449.com",        
    "whois.enom447.com",        
    "whois.enom445.com",        
    "whois.enom443.com",        
    "whois.enom441.com",        
    "whois.enom439.com",        
    "whois.enom437.com",        
    "whois.enom435.com",        
    "whois.enom433.com",        
    "whois.enom431.com",        
    "whois.enom429.com",        
    "whois.enom427.com",        
    "whois.enom425.com",        
    "whois.enom423.com",        
    "whois.enom421.com",        
    "whois.enom419.com",        
    "whois.enom417.com",        
    "whois.enom413.com",        
    "whois.enom411.com",        
    "whois.enom409.com",        
    "whois.enom407.com",        
    "whois.enom405.com",        
    "whois.enom403.com",        
    "whois.enom4.com",        
    "whois.enom399.com",        
    "whois.enom397.com",        
    "whois.enom395.com",        
    "whois.enom391.com",        
    "whois.enom389.com",        
    "whois.enom387.com",        
    "whois.enom381.com",        
    "whois.enom379.com",        
    "whois.enom377.com",        
    "whois.enom375.com",        
    "whois.enom373.com",        
    "whois.enom371.com",        
    "whois.enom3.com",        
    "whois.enom2.com",        
    "whois.enom1.com",        
    "whois.enetica.com.au",        
    "whois.encirca.com",        
    "whois.ename.com",        
    "whois.echodomain.com",        
    "whois.ebrandsecure.com",        
    "whois.easyspace.com",        
    "whois.eastnames.com",        
    "whois.eachnic.com",        
    "whois.eNom461.com",        
    "whois.eNom415.com",        
    "whois.eNom393.com",        
    "whois.eNom385.com",        
    "whois.eNom383.com",        
    "whois.dyndns.com",        
    "whois.dynanames.com",        
    "whois.dynamicdolphin.com",        
    "whois.dynadot5.com",        
    "whois.dynadot4.com",        
    "whois.dynadot3.com",        
    "whois.dynadot2.com",        
    "whois.dynadot1.com",        
    "whois.dynadot0.com",        
    "whois.dynadot.com",        
    "whois.duckbilleddomains.com",        
    "whois.dropoutlet.com",        
    "whois.dotroll.com",        
    "whois.dotnamed.com",        
    "whois.dotname.co.kr",        
    "whois.dotdomainsale.com",        
    "whois.dotarai.com",        
    "whois.dotalliance.com",        
    "whois.domus-llc.com",        
    "whois.domrobot.com",        
    "whois.domerati.com",        
    "whois.domdrill.com",        
    "whois.domainz.com",        
    "whois.domainyeti.com",        
    "whois.domainwards.com",        
    "whois.domaintimemachine.com",        
    "whois.domaintact.com",        
    "whois.domainsurgeon.com",        
    "whois.domainstreetdirect.com",        
    "whois.domainsrs.com",        
    "whois.domainsprouts.com",        
    "whois.domainsovereigns.com",        
    "whois.domainsoverboard.com",        
    "whois.domainsouffle.com",        
    "whois.domainsonly.com",        
    "whois.domainsofvalue.com",        
    "whois.domainsoftheworld.net",        
    "whois.domainsoftheday.net",        
    "whois.domainsofcourse.com",        
    "whois.domainsinthebag.com",        
    "whois.domainshype.com",        
    "whois.domainsareforever.net",        
    "whois.domainsalsa.com",        
    "whois.domainsails.net",        
    "whois.domains.domreg.lt",        
    "whois.domains.co.za",        
    "whois.domainroyale.com",        
    "whois.domainregi.com",        
    "whois.domainraker.net",        
    "whois.domainprocessor.com",        
    "whois.domainprime.com",        
    "whois.domainpicking.com",        
    "whois.domainpeople.com",        
    "whois.domainparkblock.com",        
    "whois.domainnovations.com",        
    "whois.domainnameshop.com",        
    "whois.domainname.com",        
    "whois.domainmonster.com",        
    "whois.domainmap.com",        
    "whois.domainlocal.com",        
    "whois.domainladder.com",        
    "whois.domainjungle.net",        
    "whois.domaininthehole.com",        
    "whois.domaininthebasket.com",        
    "whois.domainhysteria.com",        
    "whois.domainhood.com",        
    "whois.domainhawks.net",        
    "whois.domaingetter.com",        
    "whois.domaingazelle.com",        
    "whois.domainfalcon.com",        
    "whois.domainextreme.com",        
    "whois.domaindiscover.com",        
    "whois.domaindelights.com",        
    "whois.domaincritics.com",        
    "whois.domaincreek.com",        
    "whois.domaincraze.com",        
    "whois.domaincontext.com",        
    "whois.domaincomesaround.com",        
    "whois.domainclub.com",        
    "whois.domainclip.com",        
    "whois.domaincentre.ca",        
    "whois.domaincapitan.com",        
    "whois.domainarmada.com",        
    "whois.domainamania.com",        
    "whois.domainallies.com",        
    "whois.domainahead.com",        
    "whois.domainagent.co.nz",        
    "whois.domain2.com",        
    "whois.domain.com",        
    "whois.documentdata.li",        
    "whois.do-reg.jp",        
    "whois.dns.com.cn",        
    "whois.dm3networks.com",        
    "whois.division120.com",        
    "whois.distributeit.com.au",        
    "whois.discountdomainsuk.com",        
    "whois.discount-domain.com",        
    "whois.directnic.com",        
    "whois.dfordomains.com",        
    "whois.desertdevil.com",        
    "whois.deschutesdomains.com",        
    "whois.demys.com",        
    "whois.dattatec.com",        
    "whois.dandomain.dk",        
    "whois.dagnabit.biz",        
    "whois.curiousnet.com",        
    "whois.crystalcoal.com",        
    "whois.cronon.net",        
    "whois.crispnames.com",        
    "whois.cps-datensysteme.de",        
    "whois.corporatedomains.com",        
    "whois.corenic.net",        
    "whois.coolocean.com",        
    "whois.compuglobalhypermega.com",        
    "whois.communigal.net",        
    "whois.commerceisland.com",        
    "whois.comfydomains.com",        
    "whois.columbianames.com",        
    "whois.cnolnic.com",        
    "whois.cndns.com",        
    "whois.cn.hooyoo.com",        
    "whois.clouddomainregistry.com",        
    "whois.cheapies.com",        
    "whois.cdmon.com",        
    "whois.ccireg.com",        
    "whois.ccdomain.co.kr",        
    "whois.burnsidedomains.com",        
    "whois.bullrundomains.com",        
    "whois.bottledomains.com",        
    "whois.boterosolutions.net",        
    "whois.bookmyname.com",        
    "whois.bluerazor.com",        
    "whois.bluefractal.com",        
    "whois.blockhost.com",        
    "whois.blisternet.net",        
    "whois.blastdomains.com",        
    "whois.blacknight.com",        
    "whois.bizcn.com",        
    "whois.binero.se",        
    "whois.biglizarddomains.com",        
    "whois.bighouseservices.com",        
    "whois.bigdomainshop.com",        
    "whois.betterthanaveragedomains.com",        
    "whois.belmontdomains.com",        
    "whois.beartrapdomains.com",        
    "whois.batdomains.com",        
    "whois.basicfusion.com",        
    "whois.baronofdomains.com",        
    "whois.badger.com",        
    "whois.backslapdomains.com",        
    "whois.azprivatez.com",        
    "whois.azdomainz.com",        
    "whois.az.pl",        
    "whois.aviddomain.com",        
    "whois.ausregistryinternational.com",        
    "whois.atozdomainsmarket.com",        
    "whois.atomicdomainnames.com",        
    "whois.atlanticfriendnames.com",        
    "whois.astutium.com",        
    "whois.assorted.com",        
    "whois.asiaregister.com",        
    "whois.asiadomains.biz",        
    "whois.asadal.com",        
    "whois.aruba.it",        
    "whois.arcticnames.com",        
    "whois.arabinternetnames.com",        
    "whois.antagus.de",        
    "whois.anchovy.com",        
    "whois.alpinedomains.com",        
    "whois.allworldnames.com",        
    "whois.allglobalnames.com",        
    "whois.allearthdomains.com",
    "whois.alfena.com",        
    "whois.aitdomains.com",
    "whois.afternic.com",
    "whois.afterdarkdomainsincorporated.com",
    "whois.afriregister.com",
    "whois.aerotek.com.tr",
    "whois.advancedregistrar.com",
    "whois.adomainofyourown.com",
    "whois.activeregistrar.com",
    "whois.active24.com",
    "whois.acquirednames.com",
    "whois.accentdomains.com",
    "whois.above.com",        
    "whois.aboutdomainsolutions.com",                
    "whois.PresidentialDomains.com",                
    "whois.NameWeb.biz",
    "whois.LTNIC.com",        
    "whois.72dns.com",        
    "whois.625domains.com",
    "whois.55hl.com",        
    "whois.51hkidc.com",
    "whois.35.com",                
    "whois.2imagen.net",
    "whois.22.cn",                
    "whois.1isi.com",        
    "whois.1hostkorea.com",
    "whois.1hostjapan.com",
    "whois.1hostgermany.com",
    "whois.1hostchina.com",
    "whois.1hostcanada.com",
    "whois.1hostaustralia.com",
    "whois.123-reg.co.uk",
    "whois.101domain.com",
    "whois.0101domain.com",
    "whois.007names.com",
    "rcube.ipmirror.com/rblWhois.do",                
    "nswhois.domainregistry.com",
    "kheweul.org",                
    "grs-whois.hichina.com",
    "comnet-whois.humeia.com",
    "Whois.gabia.com",        
    "Whois.bigrock.com",
    "Whois.bigrock.com",
    "Whois.Registrar.Amazon.com",
);
```

Made for my startup company [WhoAPI.com](http://whoapi.com).

Comment: actually only 1 time. Most of these whois server only works for domains registered.

Comment: Ask whois.crsnic.net for availability check and then ask these for more details if a domain name is registered.

Comment: @EdiBudimilic Have you deployed distributed crawlers to crawl the domains' Whois info?

Comment: And this list of course change regularly because of new registrars, removed registrars, registrars changing names, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no definitive list. You may try to contact Verisign and ask them if they can extract a list of all accredited registrars.

The other possibility is to use a crawler, but as you noticed is not as accurate.

Comment: I built the list by crawling and will put it all here as an answer, as soon as I organize it.

Comment: The list will never be completed. There are domains not accessible to crawlers (because not linked), hundreds of domains are purchased or expired every day.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still reads this: As long as Verisign is a 'thin' registry, there will never be a list of whois servers. At least not a reliable one.

Verisign accredits registrars on a daily basis, and each registrar has a whois server of their own. Also, a registrar may decide to change the hostname of their whois server.

You have to make this a two-step process. First, check whois.internic.net for who is in charge of the domain, then query the registrar's whois. Registrars can get that information through the Verisign API (i.e. an extension of the EPP protocol)

I am not even sure what the list could be used for. You certainly do not want to query 1500+ whois servers trying to find the registrar in charge of a given domain

Comment: I totally agree with you :-) Note that there is an ongoing process to have .COM be thick, this is scheduled for 2018/2019 currently. When that happens registrars whois server will basically be useless.

Comment: You are correct, Patrick. Just FYI going thick has been delayed because of Europe introducing GDPR in May 2018 and there's a chance it will never happen

Comment: I still bet it will happen since IP interests will trump PI laws. Even scarier stuff has been touted at ICANN, like a centralized whois database, a single point with all data in it, cross TLDs. This nightmare is for now paused, but who knows when it will be reactivated..