# How to check if a domain exists programmatically?

Tags: dns, tld

Let's say I have Java or C or C++ or foo language on a computer with a connection to the world wide web and I want to programmatically check if a domain foo.com, or bar.net has been registered, how could I do it without relying on an outside service?

I'm looking for the principle here, code to make a connection is not needed.

Comment: I hope you don't consider the DNS and WHOIS to be "outside services", otherwise your task cannot be solved ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois). AFAIK a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) lookup might not always return a result even though the domain might still be registered.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all information, you'll need to implement the [whois protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3912.txt). I found [this wiki](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) for a list of whois servers (dutch wiki, might be less informative than the english)

Comment: That wiki page only lists very few servers. For more complete lists, see the [NirSoft WHOIS list](http://www.nirsoft.net/whois_servers_list.html) or [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507856/400056).